# I need to fetch some information from MySQL database and print it

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, select

I am trying to fecth some information from my MySQL database called "opskriftreg" and I want it to print it out, basically it has to retrieve 2x recipes from my database that are already created and list them accordingly with the recipes' "title" first then "description"

Here's my code, if this code is bollocks, i'd appriciate if someone could just show me a better example:

```
<?php

$mysqli = new mysqli ("localhost","root","","opskriftreg");
// Make a MySQL Connection

if (isset($_POST['title']) && isset($_POST['description']))
{
    $username= $_POST['title'];
    $password= $_POST['description'];
    $query = "SELECT *
                      FROM opskriftreg
                      WHERE title = '".mysql_real_escape_string($title)."'
                      AND description = '".mysql_real_escape_string($description)."'";
    $result = mysql_fetch_array(mysql_query($query));
    # ...
}
else
{
    return NULL;
}

?>
```

Thank you in advance :-)

EDIT:

Code changed to the following - received blank page where nothing is returned nor printed:

```
<?php
$mysqli = new mysqli("localhost", "root", "", "opskriftreg");

/* check connection */
if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
    printf("Connect failed: %s\n", mysqli_connect_error());
    exit();
}

$query = "SELECT title, description FROM opskriftreg ORDER by id DESC LIMIT 50,5";

if ($result = $mysqli->query($query)) {

    /* fetch object array */
    while ($row = $result->fetch_row()) {
        printf ("%s (%s)\n", $row[0], $row[1]);
    }

    /* free result set */
    $result->close();
}

/* close connection */
$mysqli->close();
?>
```

Comment: mysql_* functions are deprecated. Try using mysqli prepared statements with parameters instead. Anyway, you just want to retrieve 2 recipes? Or all of them.

Comment: currently I only have 2 recipes in my database, they consist of up to 8 values, whereas I only want to retrieve the 2 major ones that is, title and description, but at some point i'd like to fetch more perhaps. Could you perhaps be a bit more specific on what you mean with "mysql_* functions are deprecated. Try using mysqli prepared statements with parameters instead." I am still learning this, it's kind of new to me :-)

Answer (score 0):

```
echo $result['column_name'];
```

And `mysql_*` functions are deprecated, use `mysqli` instead.

https://www.php.net/mysqli_real_escape_string

Comment: I have changed my code to the following and swapped out the value names from the template with my own here's a link: whenever i run it, i just get a blank page nothing is printed :-(

http://us2.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-row.php

Comment: Have you replaced `column_name` by the column you need? And add `LIMIT 1` to the end of your query for in case your table contains titles and descriptions

Comment: Hey again, I've edited the question with new code I've gotten from the website you linked me, it looked correct, yet it still doesn't work, it prints nothing, just a blank screen, what are your thoughts about it? :-)

Answer (score 0):

Try this, look for the changes I've made.

```
<?php
$mysqli = new mysqli("localhost", "root", "", "opskriftreg");

/* check connection */
if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
    printf("Connect failed: %s\n", mysqli_connect_error());
    exit();
}

$query = "SELECT title, description FROM opskriftreg ORDER by id DESC";

$statement = $mysqli->prepare($query);
$statement->execute();

$results = $statement->get_result();

while ($result = $results->fetch_assoc()) {
    printf ("%s (%s)\n", $result['title'], $result['description']);
}

/* close connection */
$mysqli->close();
?>
```